# Neutrino Oscillation Transition Probability With CP Violation

Tags: symmetry, neutrinos, cp-violation

The transition probability for neutrino vacuum oscillation is

$P_{\nu_{\alpha}\rightarrow\nu_{\beta}}=\delta_{\alpha\beta}-4\sum_{k>j}\text{Re}\left[U^{*}_{\alpha k}U_{\beta k}U_{\alpha j}U^{*}_{\beta j} \right]\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\Delta m^{2}_{kj}L}{4E}\right)+2\sum_{k>j}\text{Im}\left[U^{*}_{\alpha k}U_{\beta k}U_{\alpha j}U^{*}_{\beta j} \right]\sin\left(\frac{\Delta m^{2}_{kj}L}{4E}\right)$

If we consider the transition probability for 
$P_{\nu_{\beta}\rightarrow\nu_{\alpha}}$, the only change becomes from mixing matrix. If mixing matrix is real $U=U^{*}$, the transition probabilities become equal. The real mixing matrix means CP violation phase is zero.

On the other hand, CP symmetry is related that neutrino oscillations and anti neutrino oscillations behaves similarly: CP$[\nu_{\alpha}\rightarrow\nu_{\beta}]\rightarrow \overline{\nu}_{\alpha}\rightarrow\overline{\nu}_{\beta}$. T symmetry is T$[\nu_{\alpha}\rightarrow\nu_{\beta}]\rightarrow\nu_{\beta}\rightarrow\nu_{\alpha}$

Is CP violation phase is related to T symmetry? I know Lorentz symmetry, CPT, is conserved every time.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are exactly asking? "What am I missing?" implies you want to resolve a contradiction, but I don't see any.

Comment: If CP Phase does not equal to zero, it seems T symmetry is broken. I can not make any relations between CP phase and T symmetry. I try to understand this relation.

Comment: It arises purely from CPT conservation. If CP is not conserved, then T must be broken in order to conserve CPT.